# Internet Explorer has no post data (request body), whereas Google Chrome does, same actions?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome

The form is loaded with Ajax to the page based on a  selection from a separate form. Google Chrome posts with data, IE posts with no data to speak of. What is the issue here?

Forms (Initial Select and next form) in IE:

```
<div id="client-form-div" style="padding-top: 15px; clear: both;"><form name="ClientRegistrationForm" disabled="0" id="ClientRegistrationForm" action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" country="1" identity="901221025" firstname="" middlename="" lastname="" race="1" emailaddress="" phonenumber="0110801" faxnumber="" cellnumber="" usertype="4" code="" sat_id="0" new="0" gender="0" dob="1990-12-21" region_id="0" smme_id="26" active="1" entrydate="2013-01-22 10:30:17" username="" userid="63164"><dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="country-label">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd id="country-element">
<input name="country" id="country" type="hidden" value="1"></dd>
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="identity-label"><label class="required" for="identity">ID number:</label></dt>
<dd id="identity-element">
<input name="identity" class="col-md-9 form-control" id="identity" type="text" maxlength="13" readonly="" value="90125"><ul class="good" id="good-identity"><li class="color-green"><i class="color-green align-glyph glyphicons circle_ok"></i> </li></ul></dd></div>
<dt id="userid-label">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd id="userid-element">
<input name="userid" id="userid" type="hidden" value="63164"></dd>
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="firstname-label"><label class="required" for="firstname">First Name:</label></dt>
<input name="cellnumber" class="col-md-9 form-control" id="cellnumber" type="text" maxlength="10" value=""></dd></div>
<dt id="region-label">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd id="region-element">
<input name="region" id="region" type="hidden" value="0"></dd>
<dt id="usertype-label">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd id="usertype-element">
<input name="usertype" id="usertype" type="hidden" value="4"></dd>
<dt id="submit-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="submit-element">
<input name="submit" class="btn-flat primary btn-next pull-right" id="submit" style="margin-right: 15px;" type="submit" value="Next"></dd></dl></form></div>
```

Forms in Chrome:

```
<div id="init-form-div"><form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post"><dl class="zend_form">
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="type-label"><label for="type" class="optional">Identification Type:</label></dt>
<dd class="ui-custom span5">
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="0" label="---Select---">---Select---</option>
    <option value="1" label="South African ID number">South African ID number</option>
    <option value="2" label="Passport Number">Passport Number</option>
</select></dd></div></dl></form></div>
<div id="client-form-div" style="padding-top: 15px;clear: both;"><form id="ClientRegistrationForm" name="ClientRegistrationForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" userid="63164" username="" usertype="4" emailaddress="" entrydate="2013-01-22 10:30:17" active="1" firstname="Bue" middlename="Nt" lastname="Masemola" phonenumber="0110852001" faxnumber="" cellnumber="" smme_id="269" region_id="0" dob="1990-12-21" gender="0" race="1" disabled="0" new="0" country="1" identity="90185" sat_id="0" code="" action=""><dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="country-label">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd id="country-element">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="1" id="country"></dd>
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="identity-label"><label for="identity" class="required">ID number:</label></dt>
<dd id="identity-element">
<input type="text" name="identity" id="identity" value="901285" class="col-md-9 form-control" maxlength="13" readonly="" ><ul id="good-identity" class="good"><li class="color-green"><i class="color-green align-glyph glyphicons circle_ok"></i> </li></ul></dd></div>

<select name="race" id="race">
    <option value="0" label="---Select---">---Select---</option>
    <option value="1" label="Black" selected="selected">Black</option>
    <option value="2" label="Coloured">Coloured</option>
    <option value="3" label="Asian">Asian</option>
    <option value="4" label="White">White</option>
</select></dd></div>
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="disabled-label"><label for="disabled" class="required">Disabled:</label></dt>
<dd class="ui-custom span5">
<select name="disabled" id="disabled">
    <option value="0" label="No" selected="selected">No</option>
    <option value="1" label="Yes">Yes</option>
</select></dd></div>
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="emailaddress-label"><label for="emailaddress" class="optional">E-Mail Address:</label></dt>
<dd id="emailaddress-element">
<input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" value="" class="col-md-9 form-control"></dd></div>
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="phonenumber-label"><label for="phonenumber" class="optional">Phone Number:</label></dt>
<dd id="phonenumber-element">
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" value="0110852001" class="col-md-9 form-control" maxlength="10"></dd></div>
<div class="col-md-12 field-box"><dt id="faxnumber-label"><label for="faxnumber" class="optional">Fax Number:</label></dt>
<dd id="region-element">
<input type="hidden" name="region" value="0" id="region"></dd>
<dt id="usertype-label">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd id="usertype-element">
<input type="hidden" name="usertype" value="4" id="usertype"></dd>
<dt id="submit-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="submit-element">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next" class="btn-flat primary btn-next pull-right" style="margin-right:15px;"></dd></dl></form></div>
```

**Google Chrome Post Data:**

```
country:1
identity:901285
userid:63164
firstname:Busi
middlename:biseng
lastname:Mala
race:1
disabled:0
emailaddress:
phonenumber:011001
faxnumber:
cellnumber:
region:0
usertype:4
submit:Next
```

**IE Request Body:**

(Empty)

Comment: This is a basic suggestion, but the last time I had issues between web providers, it was my security set-up in IE. All the cookies were being prevented from loading and it threw a completely unrelated error, saying that my authentication was wrong. Have you checked your settings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
<form name="ClientRegistrationForm" disabled="0" id="ClientRegistrationForm" action=""
 enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" country="1"
 identity="9012" firstname="B" middlename="Nthabi"
 lastname="M" emailaddress=""
 faxnumber="" cellnumber="" usertype="4" code="" sat_id="0" new="0"
 gender="0" dob="1990-12-21" region_id="0" active="1"
 entrydate="2013-01-22 10:30:17" username="" userid="63164">
```

specifically the: `disabled="0"` part.

In ie11, this disables the form and prevents any post data from being posted.

It is recommended not to put your parameters in the form, as it is a security risk and useless.

The reason this is happening is because you are using `Zend Framework` `Zend form __construct()`.
Then when constructing you use:

```
Parent::__construct($record);
```

Where it should be

```
Parent::__construct();
```